# Get today's date in data to use for vuetify component

Tags: vue.js

I want to use a vuetify calendar that highlights todays date, how would I get it in the data or set it as a variable in the data?

This is the example calendar code on the vuetify page. Calendar Page. This is the first example the week view.

```
<template>
  <v-row>
    <v-col>
      <v-sheet height="400">
        <v-calendar
          ref="calendar"
          :now="today"
          :value="today"
          :events="events"
          color="primary"
          type="week"
        ></v-calendar>
      </v-sheet>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      today: '2019-01-08',
      eventsMap: [
        {
          name: 'Weekly Meeting',
          start: '2019-01-07 09:00',
          end: '2019-01-07 10:00',
        },
        {
          name: 'Thomas\' Birthday',
          start: '2019-01-10',
        },
        {
          name: 'Mash Potatoes',
          start: '2019-01-09 12:30',
          end: '2019-01-09 15:30',
        },
      ],
    }),
    mounted () {
      this.$refs.calendar.scrollToTime('08:00')
    },
  }
</script>
```

How can I get the current date and set it to a variable in the data something like this?

```
today: currentDate
```

Answer (score 2):

For Vuetify calendar component, add the following to data: () => ({

> ```
> today : new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable in the data section:

```
today: new Date()
```

This will give you today's date. Then you may use it in your component

Comment: Now I get this error `Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "now". Expected String with value "Thu Jan 02 2020 12:40:01 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)", got Date ` Could I turn the date into a string?

Comment: @Nancy today : (new Date()).toString()

Comment: I get this now `Invalid prop: custom validator check failed for prop "now".`

Comment: Try this
`date : new Date(),
  today : date.getFullYear()+'-'+(date.getMonth()+1)+'-'+date.getDate(),`

Comment: That causes a lot of errors now only for the calendar but other errors pop up as well the main ones says `Error in data(): "ReferenceError: date is not defined"`

Comment: Would it be easier to do this in the controller and just send today's date in a string?